# need help setting an image button in Google sites to be responsive to mouse events?

Tags: html, css, google-sites

Ok, so im creating a website and to make it look fancier, I need to make the image responsive to the mouse (i.e. when the cursor is over the image, when the image is click, etc.) Does anyone know the code or another way of doing it? I am using google sites. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using JQuery to select and add some actions to your images have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.selfcontained.us/2008/03/08/simple-jquery-image-rollover-script/) it is quite good.

You can take the idea and change it to your liking.